# Security Scan supee-10415 false positive?

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10415, security-scan-tool

Magento 1 supee-10415 installed in my magento but when i checked that in magereports it's show safe and checked in magento security scan tool it's show " SUPEE-10415 has not been detected!". 
Any one have idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing with grey background color in magereport ? 
Recheck in your root if it is correctly installed

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

Check the magereport suggestion on why the patch is not been detected [link](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-apply-magento-patches-hypernode-knowledge-base/):

MageReport keeps saying the security patch isn’t installed
We found out that there are several reasons why patches can come out as uninstalled on Magereport.com, so we recommend you to check the following:

- When compilation is enabled in the backend of your Magento, the
  Magento patch doesn’t work properly. Disable compilation (navigate to
  System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button) to
  make sure the patch works. After disabling compilation, check your
  site with magereport.com again. If the check still comes out as not
  installed, try re-compiling.
- Check if the patch is installed in the correct directory;
- Reload your opcode cache, webserver, PHP-FPM process and possible
  other caches. The old code might be still be active;
- Check your shops’ .htaccess. If you’ve made any adjustements in your
  .htaccess, it’s possible the patch is only partially installed;

Comment: magereports show patch detected but it's not detected in magento security scan tool and magereport background color is green